# Digital Ocean Spaces S3: Is it possible to add access-control-allow-origin: * to all requests?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, digital-ocean, cors

If you curl my image

```
curl -i https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg
```

you will see that there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response.

If you curl like this, the header is set:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://example.com/" -i https://local-spaces.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/test.jpg
```

Now I wonder, because all big CDN pages always set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, even when `Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors`.

To test it, do this:

```
curl -i https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/02a788f9e7f55880601ed240a0e3142a/5E29CBDE/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/72271766_155986088835033_6677460235579468035_n.jpg\?_nc_ht\=scontent.cdninstagram.com
```

or

```
curl -i https://loremflickr.com/480/640/girl,boy,man,men,woman\?lock\=4446
```

Answer (score 1):

The support reached out to me:

> At the moment, there isn't any way to force this. Without an Origin set, the header will not be served. It is possible to use a proxy service, however that may not be the best fit for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Digital Ocean Spaces don't allow * CORS headers in their UI. I ended up having to use Just CORS (https://justcors.com) which is a proxy that adds CORS headers to responses, to circumvent this.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Can you please declare your affiliation with `justcors.com`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).